# How to fix the " The multi-part identifier "word" could not be bound" error

Tags: c#, sql

I want to insert some datas from a notepad, but i got this error:"The multi-part identifier "id.localitate" could not be bound."

Here is the code:

```
string[] siruri = sir.Split(split);
cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Localitati(nume) values(@localitate)", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("localitate", siruri[0].Trim());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd = new SqlCommand("Select id.localitate from Localitati where nume=@nume", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nume", siruri[0].Trim());

int idlocalitate = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

int nrzile;
```

Comment: `id.localitate` -- that's your problem - that's looking for the column `localitate` on a table called `id`, which probably isn't what you meant. Did you just mean to "select id ..."?

Comment: id.localitate is a column on a tabel called Localitati.

Comment: @AdrianGbr try `SELECT [id.localitate] FROM Localitati` ...

Comment: @AdrianGbr so the column is called "id", or is the column called "localitate"?

Comment: You might also want to look at `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and/or the `OUTPUT` clause. There's no reason to execute *two* queries where the second is just trying to pick up the effects of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your command **id.localitate is a column on a tabel called Localitati**, you need to use the column name with square brackets as `[id.localitate]`, so the code will be:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [id.localitate] from Localitati where nume=@nume", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cause there is no such table alias defined in your query. It should be then like

```
Select id.localitate from Localitati id where nume=@nume
```

Or just the query without any table alias

```
Select localitate from Localitati where nume=@nume
```

per your comment *id.localitate is a column on a tabel called Localitate*

You need to escape the column then using `[]` like `Select [id.localitate]` or `Select "id.localitate"` though I would never recommend having a column with such name. Define your DB objects name (Table, Column) properly

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you got a Table "Localitati" like this:

```
| Id | Name | FatherId |
| 1  | A    | null     |
| 2  | B    | 1        |
```

You could run a Select like this:

```
SELECT Id FROM Localitati WHERE 1 = 1;
```

In your query you can set synonyms for your tables to select the corret column. This is needed if you want to join to the table itself:

```
   SELECT a.Id, b.Id
     FROM Localitati a
LEFT JOIN Localitati b
       ON a.Id = b.FatherId
    WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Your question said, that your columns name is "id.Localitati" (which id don't think). If this is the case, you have to quote your column-name:

```
| Id.Localitati | Name | FatherId |
| 1             | A    | null     |
| 2             | B    | 1        |
```

The query would look like this:

```
   SELECT a."Id.Localitati", b."Id.Localitati"
     FROM Localitati a
LEFT JOIN Localitati b
       ON a."Id.Localitati" = b.FatherId
    WHERE 1 = 1;
```

But you shouldn't use dots in any names..